# Time Complexity of Array based Disjoint-Set data structure

Tags: algorithm, disjoint-sets

I was solving [this](https://www.codechef.com/problems/DISHOWN) question on CodeChef and going through the [editorial](https://discuss.codechef.com/questions/47241/dishown-editorial).

Here's the pseudo-code for the implemented disjoint-set algorithm :

```
Initialize parent[i] = i  
Let S[i] denote the initial array.

int find(int i)
    int j
    if(parent[i]==i)
                return i
    else
        j=find(parent[i])
        //Path Compression Heuristics
        parent[i]=j
        return j

set_union(int i,int j)
    int x1,y1
    x1=find(i)
    y1=find(j)
    //parent of both of them will be the one with the highest score
    if(S[x1]>S[y1])
        parent[y1]=x1
    else if ( S[x1] < S[y1])
        parent[x1]=y1

solve()
    if(query == 0)
        Input x and y
        px = find(x)
        py = find(y)
        if(px == py)
            print "Invalid query!"
        else
            set_union(px,py)
    else
        Input x.
        print find(x)
```

What is the time complexity of `union` and `find` ?

IMO, the time complexity of `find` is `O(depth)`, so in worst case, if I am not using path-comression, the complexity turns out to be O(n). Since `union` also uses `find`, it also has the complexity of O(n). If instead we throw out the `find` from `union` and instead pass the parents of two sets to `union`, complexity of `union` is O(1). Please correct me, if I am wrong.

If path compression is applied, then what is the time complexity?

Answer (score 1):

Without path compression : When we use linked list representation of disjoint sets and the weighted-union heuristic, a sequence of m MAKE-SET, UNION by rank , FIND-SET operations takes place where n of which are MAKE-SET operations. So , it takes O(m+ nlogn).

With only  path compression :  The running time is
 theta( n + f * ( 1 + (log (base( 2 + f/n))  n ) ) )
where f is no of find sets operations and n is no of make set operations

With both union by rank and path compression: 
 O( m*p(n )) where p(n) is less than equal to 4

Comment: Where can I find the proof of the complexity $\Theta( n + f * ( 1 + (log (base( 2 + f/n)) n ) ) )$?

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity of both union and find *would be* linear if you use neither ranks nor path compression, because in the worst case, it would be necessary to iterate through the entire tree in every query.

If you use only union by ranks, without path compression, the complexity would be logarithmic.
[The detailed solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_O(log*n)_time_complexity_of_union%E2%80%93find) is quite difficult to understand, but basically you wouldn't traverse the entire tree, because the depth of the tree would only increase if the ranks of the two sets are equal. So the iteration would be O(log*n) per query.

If you use the path compression optimization, the complexity would be even lower, because it "flattens" the tree, thus reducing the traversal. Its amortized time per operation is **even faster than O(n)**, as you can read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure#Disjoint-set_forests).

Comment: Can you please talk in terms of Array based approach, with reference to the pseudo code posted. I want to know the time complexity of that particular approach.

Comment: Ok, so basically you want a union-find _with_ path compression _but without_ union by ranks. Its complexity is O(log*n) per query, because even in the worst case, the new parent of a dish is the root of the tree, so in the next query the path would be already compressed.

You can see it [here](https://books.google.ru/books?id=oK3UWxg_UhsC&pg=PA224&lpg=PA224&dq=%22without+union+by+rank%22&source=bl&ots=iGGO7XKp6L&sig=U76thEmxJZ4oadMQPRbW8sA9tDI&hl=ru&ei=PDeFS5OFNJPw-QbQxIyeAQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result#v=onepage&q=%22without%20union%20by%20rank%22&f=false)